# css float:left with position left

Tags: html, css

Why does this not work? I have assigned a bunch of divs with float:left and want to set the position of the first element's position and then have all of the siblings position update with it.

For example I set the first element's css left:50px. I was expecting that the siblings would all shift as well but they do not, they stay in their position relative to the parent.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wrap {margin:10px; width:auto; height:70px; background:#ccc; position:relative;}
    .floater {width:50px; height:50px; float:left; background:blue; margin:10px 0px 0px 10px; position:relative; left:10px;}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="floater" style="left:50px; background:red"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>
    <div class="floater"></div>                             
</div>
```

I noticed that if I use margin-left then I get the behavior that I want but I do NOT want to use margin-left because I need to query the current position of the divs from time to time.

Any thoughts on how to achieve what I want? Thanks.

Jacob

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZurxT/

Comment: This is expected behavior: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning . Other elements follow the flow of a relatively positioned elements original position. 

Perhaps if you explain more on what you're trying to do (i.e. why margin-left doesn't work for you and what "the need to query the 'current position'" means), we can provide better help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct rendering for `left` -- the `left` property is intended for use with `position`, to adjust the positioning of a given element without affecting anything else around it.

Typically you'd use `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` to create a fixed layout for a group of elements. Each of them would be `position:relative;` (or `absolute` or `fixed`) and have their own positioning which would place them *relative to their parent element, not relative to each other*.

This is obviously quite at odds with the concept of `float`, where elements are very much positioned relative to each other.

Two solutions come to mind which will do what you want:

1) put `padding-left:50px;` on the container `wrap` div element instead of `left:50px;` on the floated element as you have it.

2) use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`. This tends to make layout work easier than with floats. I prefer the `inline-block` solution, because I find floats to be quite painful to work with sometimes, especially when I want to fine-tune my layout.

See my JSFiddle examples: http://jsfiddle.net/xgKBc/

Comment: ah, display:inline-block works exactly how I needed. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can either give every floater a relative position of 50px on the left side. Or you can add a padding-left of 50px to the wrapper.

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/ZurxT/1/)** with both examples.